# Displaying an Image and Content slider beside each other

Tags: css

I have an image slider and a content slider beside each other.  The image slider is floating left.  When the screen size is reduced (ctrl + roll mouse wheel) the content slider drops beneath the image slider.

http://www.tall-shiprace.com/

Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS Style

From

```
#BJ_ImageSlider_164_out.gallery_out {
background: #333;
}
```

TO

```
#BJ_ImageSlider_434_out.gallery_out {
background: #333;
width: 729px !important;
}
```